# How to fix MissingPluginException (package_info) caused by get_version plugin?

Tags: testing, plugins, dart, flutter

I have a flutter App and I am writing a test case that compares the currentVersion of the App with the latestVersion available. The function simply takes values for currentVersion and latestVersion and returns true or false depending on whether currentVersion<=latestVersion.

I am using get_version plugin to extract the currentVersion of the App. LatestVersion holds a value one than that for testing purposes.

This same call works in the rest of the App. It's creating an issue only  in the test case.

I tried upgrading from 0.0.8 to 0.1.0 but in vain.

```
    void main() {
      test('checkAppVersion', () async {
        String currentVersion = await GetVersion.projectVersion;


expect(
    checkAppVersionTest(
        Version.parse(currentVersion), Version.parse(latestVersion)),
    true);


  });
}

    bool checkAppVersionTest(Version currentVersion, Version latestVersion) { bool updateRequired = false;
      if (currentVersion < latestVersion) {
        updateRequired = true;
      }
      return updateRequired;
    }
```

I am getting the following error:

> MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/package_info)
>   package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart 300:7  MethodChannel.invokeMethod
>   ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
>   dart:async                                                _AsyncAwaitCompleter.completeError
>   package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart        MethodChannel.invokeMethod
>   ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
>   dart:async                                                _asyncThenWrapperHelper
>   package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart        MethodChannel.invokeMethod
>   package:package_info/package_info.dart 38:17              PackageInfo.fromPlatform

Works fine when I hard code the currentVersion value.

Please suggest a way around this.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: same issue. any solution?

Comment: Nope, didn't find any solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you're using Android Studio or similar and clicking the 'Play' button to run your tests.
I tried this and got the same result as you.
However it seems the tests doesn't actually run on a device by clicking this button - which is required by the plugin, so by running it from the terminal, and specifying the file - it seems to run fine:

```
flutter run test.dart
```

You will need to add the following at the first line of your main(), otherwise you'll get a different error:

```
TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Final code:

```
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:get_version/get_version.dart';
import 'package:pub_semver/pub_semver.dart';

void main() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  test('checkAppVersion', () async {
    String currentVersion = await GetVersion.projectVersion;
    String latestVersion = '0.0.1';
    expect(checkAppVersionTest(Version.parse(currentVersion), Version.parse(latestVersion)), false);
  });
}

bool checkAppVersionTest(Version currentVersion, Version latestVersion) {
  bool updateRequired = false;
  if (currentVersion < latestVersion) {
    updateRequired = true;
  }
  return updateRequired;
}
```

If anyone comes across a similar issue while running your app normally, try to terminate your app and run
`flutter clean` in the terminal.